# Where is the text expansion file located with OS X?

Tags: filesystem, system-settings

I'd like to give a colleague all of my text expansions without her having to re-enter them on her Mac. I was hoping to locate the file, then simply send her a copy to replace her own. (She doesn't use the feature.) I've searched the `Library` folder, but can't locate the file that contains the text expansion data.

Does anyone know where the file produced by `System Preferences > Keyboard > Text` is kept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Mavericks, they're stored in NSUserReplacementItems in the global preferences. However, since Mavericks, the replacements are stored in…

```
~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/$USER~*/UserDictionary/*/store/UserDictionary.db
```

Comment: When I look at the contents of that file in TextWrangler, I don't the any text that indicates the expansions are in there. Another UserDictionary.db file is along a similar path at ~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/$USER~*/UserDictionary/*/store/UserDictionary.db. That file has the expansion text. Could this be the one to copy to my colleague?

Comment: @user77822 Yes — I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this a few times: I've deleted all of the files in that UserDictionary folder and restarted my Mac (10.9.3), but the expansion text list (Sys Pref:Keyboard:Text) remains. I'm thinking that there may be some cache file somewhere.

I'm trying to delete the file itself, because the whole text expansion system on my Mac has gone wonky. If I delete any shortcut, and then add it in again with a different expansion, it just doesn't work. So only about half of the 80+ expansions currently expand, while the other half work fine.

(I'm referring to the files found in ~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/$USER~*/UserDictionary/*/store/UserDictionary.db )

Comment: There's a lot more information on this issue (and some possible solutions) here: https://michaelkummer.com/2014/11/11/icloud-keyboard-shortcuts-that-keep-returning/