# Copying iOS autocorrect custom dictionary among devices

Tags: ios, dictionary, spellcheck, auto-complete, autocorrect

Is it possible to create a file of autocorrect entries for iOS devices and deploy it to all my company iPads (8 of them right now)? There are about 150 autocorrect entries that we'd like to setup on all the iPads.  Ideally, we would find a way to manage them centrally.

We tried [textexpander](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textexpander-3-+-custom-keyboard/id917416298?mt=8) on the iPads (love it for the Mac - its indespensible), but on the iPads its actually slow. The keyboard lag led to riots among my staff.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually want an autocorrect for a misspelling or a keyboard shortcut for an abbreviation?

If you sync the iPads with the same computer they should have all the same keyboard shortcuts. i.e. "omw" becomes "On my way!" (without the quotes).

That shortcut I created on my iPhone but I am typing now on my Mac Pro and it expanded to the full phrase as I typed it.

I use this one all the time "mcx" becomes "Mac OSX".

Look at the "System Preferences > Keyboard > Text" tab for shortcuts on your computer. If you create them on the desktop computer they should sync to your iOS device(s) and vice versa.

Check this link here if you want to try to copy the actual file:
[Where is the text expansion file located with OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130227/where-is-the-text-expansion-file-located-with-os-x)

Happy Wednesday!

Answer (score 0):

You need only login to the same iCloud Account on all your devices. Their custom dictionaries (this would be were your dictionary additions are added) will then sync through iCloud. The same applies to keyboard shortcuts/expansions.

Available since iOS 6. If you are using iOS 8 with a third-party keyboard, this feature may not work depending on how well the third-party keyboard integrate with these services [iOS 8.1 seems to have broken](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6564073) the keyboard shortcut/expansion feature.